# How to make this program print the index of searched character in array otherwise it will print not found?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main () {
char arr[7];
char x;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    cin >> arr[i];
}
cin >> x;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (x == arr[i])
        cout << i << endl;

    else {
        cout <<"Not found";
    break;
    }
}

}
```

This program supposed to receive 7 characters and store them in an array then the user have to search for a character, then the program will print the index of that character otherwise, It will print not found, This problem here is when I enter `a b c d e f g` then search i.e: `a` It will print `0` `not found` What is happening here? My debugger is bugged. so I can't use it. I hope you understand my question. How to make it print only index of a character that the user searched for, if not found the program will print `not found`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code quoted below, if `x != arr[0]`, the `if` condition will be false in the first turn of `for` loop, thus directly go to `else` part, which means printing "Not found" and `break`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (x == arr[i])
        cout << i << endl;

    else {
        cout <<"Not found";
    break;
    }
}
```

Correct way:

```
bool found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    if (x == arr[i]) {
        cout << i << endl;
        found = true;
    }
}

if ( !found ) {
    cout <<"Not found";
}
```

Comment: This works fine, but when there are more similar characters, it will print only the first index found. not every index that have the same character.

Comment: @SarahAhmed You will just need to keep searching the array until you reach the end, instead of leaving early if the first value is found.